# Get last published news from table with multiple companies

Tags: mysql

This is my news table:

```
id  |   company_id  |   published  
1   |   1           |   2014-06-20         
2   |   1           |   2014-06-19         
3   |   2           |   2014-06-12
```

I want to get the last published item, for each company.
Is this possible with 1 query? I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`company_id`), id, published 
FROM `newsitems` 
ORDER BY `published` DESC
```

This is the result what i want:

```
id | published 
1  | 2014-06-20  
3  | 2014-06-12
```

The company-table structure:

```
id  |   companyname |   status  
1   |   'name1'     |   'active'        
2   |   'name2'     |   'active'         
3   |   'name3'     |   'active'
```

Comment: post your company table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is to reserve the combination of id and published. Your sample data is too simple to see the difference. Here is something that should work but looks a bit ugly. There might be something nicer :-)

```
SELECT id, published FROM newsitems
WHERE concat(published, "_", id, "_", company_id) IN (
  SELECT max(concat(published, "_", id, "_", company_id))
  FROM newsitems
  GROUP BY company_id
)
ORDER BY id
```

Try it with this sample data:

```
id  |   company_id  |   published
1   |   1           |   2014-06-20
2   |   1           |   2014-06-19
3   |   2           |   2014-06-12
4   |   1           |   2014-06-21
5   |   2           |   2014-06-13
6   |   2           |   2014-06-11
```

Result should be:

```
id | published 
4  | 2014-06-21
5  | 2014-06-13
```

This is what you told us that you want. For this case the company table isn't needed. To do something with company name or company status you have to join the tables.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL should be right:

```
SELECT `company_id` As `id`, `published` 
FROM `newsitems`
GROUP BY `company_id` 
ORDER BY `published` DESC, `id` DESC
```

The `id DESC` is used to get the latest newsitem if the published date is the same in two entries.

Comment: This doesn't sort de news items before it groups the company_id

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables and order by the max date published.

```
  select n.id, MAX(n.published) From
    newsitems n leftjoin company c on n.company_id = c.id
    ORDER BY MAX(n.published) DESC;
```